# How can I make it possible for all users to log in without a password?

Tags: login, password

I have a system with two accounts.  The primary (and administrator) account automatically logs in at boot time and is used 95% of the time.  On occasion I need to logout and switch to a secondary account dedicated to part time work which is set to log in without a password (just click login).  When I log out of that account I would like to log back into the other without a password but I don't see any way to set that as an option in the "Users and Accounts".

I know how to get disable the password when the screen goes to sleep and I want to keep the password intact because it seems like it is necessary for administrative purposes.  Having something that could easily be reversed would also be a plus (in other words just re-enable the password for **login**).

This is marked as a duplicate, but that question does not answer my specifics and the methods referenced do not show up in my stock 13.04 install.  I have placed an answer below that did fit the bill.

Comment: Different question.  I want to maintain the password just not have to enter it at the login screen.  I actually used an answer that was deleted and it worked fine which I may repost unless there is a really good reason not to??    gpasswd -a username nopasswdlogin

Comment: Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password/281093#281093).

Comment: @Mitch: That appears (am I mistaken?) to remove the password which I don't want to do, and only have one admin account.  You have much more knowledge than I do in such matters so I'll ask, the gpasswd method seems to work fine.  Is there a danger involved that I don't know about?

Comment: None that I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this is what I came up with.  Logins are without password entry, just click the "Log In" button.  Password is preserved and works fine whenever prompted.  I haven't tried to reverse it but can't see any reason that wouldn't work.

```
sudo gpasswd -a <USERNAME> nopasswdlogin
```

In all fairness this answer was posted earlier but deleted.  I don't remember by who but I'm glad I saw it because it is spot on.

To re-enable the password query it would be

```
sudo gpasswd -d <USERNAME> nopasswdlogin
```

A little more information can be found at http://www.tuxgarage.com/2012/07/disable-enable-passwordless-login.html

Answer (score 0):

So you wanted to remove the password of your primary account?
I don't know if this will work but try this.

Open your terminal and type this:

```
sudo passwd -d *username*
```