# Ubuntu 13.10 Security Key

Tags: installation, 13.10

I was attempting to install Ubuntu 13.10 today and it came up with a screen asking for me to setup a security key.  In the first place, I'm not sure what a security key is, but It said I would have to enter it everytime I booted Ubuntu so I assume it's the same thing as a logon password in Windows 8.

Is there anyway I can bypass this step without setting up a security key or logon password?  I hate these things and have always avoided them in Windows.  I don't need them as there is never anyone but myself and my wife on our computers.  We are retired, no children  or nieces, nephews, friends, etc. who ever use our computer and we don't have any security information such as SS #, etc.  on it.

Also,  I quit the installation at this point but I was not seeing any of the screen prompts as listed in the setup instructions on the Ubuntu website.  Has the setup for Ubuntu 13.10 changed since these instructions were written?  Thanks

Comment: Did you follow these instructions? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest If so, at which step number (image number) did you see the question about security key? Password is created at **step 8.** At this step you can also choose to **Encrypt your home folder**. If you do this you will be prompted for extra security key. Please edit your question with the new information.

Comment: I don't know what step number it was but the Encrypt your home folder option never appeared on my setup screen.  I'll try it again and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

- During user setup, make sure that "Encrypt my home folder" is unchecked.
- You can't install Ubuntu without a password, but during user setup, you can select the option to automatically log in. Then, you will not be prompted for a password when the computer starts up and will be taken directly to a desktop. You will be asked for a password for administrative tasks, sometimes, but this feature is useful because it will make you think twice and make sure you know what you are doing before continuing on. It is important, in Linux, to distinguish between ordinary user tasks and administrative tasks that may make large or harmful changes to the system.
- When you get to the step where it asks you for an Ubuntu One account, you can either skip the step and click "Log in Later", or follow [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867/how-can-i-stop-being-prompted-to-unlock-the-default-keyring-on-boot) to create the account but skip the login keyring that would appear since you have automatic log in enabled.

Related question:

[Can I set my user account to have no password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password)

Comment: As stated above, The "Encrypt my home folder" never appeared on any of the screens, at least as far as I got.  But the automatic login option sounds okay just as long as I don't have to type in an I.D. and password everytime I boot.