# Employee left blank password on Ubuntu 15 graphic install

Tags: permissions, login, password, sudo, root

My boss wants a blank password on the desktop running the Ubuntu 15.04.  The system logs me into the account directly but whenever I try to sudo command anything and it asks for the password, leaving the space blank doesn't work.  I have been researching this for about an hour and I can't come up with any results that really help.  I know I can't log in the root account directly, but I also can't do anything as long as the blank password isn't working.  I use Kali pretty regularly but I'm not familiar with Ubuntu as much.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The employee who set up the machine set a normal password then "deleted the credentials so it would log in automatically".  We've resolved to just reinstall and cut out losses, not waste anymore time on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu setup, you cannt set a blank password. That's how UNIX and UNIX-like operating systems work to protect some of the administrators functionnality that can affect the system. So there is a password and you have to find the one that set it up.

Comment: There is no answer here, so this isn't helpful. -1

Comment: This confirms my talk : http://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password it's impossible that you can set your password blank from the ubuntu setup page. In fact there is no solution to solve that except saving all the data and re install ubuntu

Comment: Well that page you linked states that it can be done from the terminal. And what I've found, from a couple misinstalls on a laptop with no backlight, is that if you accidentally set a blank password, you will end up with a (seemingly) unusable system. I agree with your solution