# `sudo`, `gksu` and `gksudo` without password

Tags: permissions, sudo, authentication, gksu, gksudo

In [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/), I am surprised that if my administrator account does not have a password, `sudo`, `gksu` and `gksudo` won't prompt me for one! (it is not caused by `/etc/sudoers`). In Ubuntu, [they will ask me for a password and if I give it an empty one, they will not let me pass.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password)

1. How does Fedora do this? (what are the technical design details in Fedora that causes this behavior?)
2. How can I make Ubuntu behave like this? (how to configure Ubuntu to act like Fedora in this regard?)

Similar questions have been asked many times before, but they only address `sudo` and not `gksu`, `gksudo` nor any other graphical tool. Also, neither `sudo -i` nor editing `/etc/sudoers` is needed; this is default Fedora behavior.

Of course this is probably **not recommended**, I just ask this so that I can learn more about how Linux works.

Comment: As for the recent edit that added for reopening request, How do you know that Fedora doesn't modify the `/etc/sudoers` file? And both `gksu` and `gksudo` are graphical counterpart of `sudo`.

Comment: @AnwarShah In Fedora, the lines with "NOPASSWD" in `/etc/sudoers` are commented out. Also, you can easily reproduce this Fedora behavior. Get a fresh Fedora installation, use `sudo passwd -d` to delete admin account. Log in to the admin account without a password and, for example, click "Unlock" in "User Accounts" (or "Users" or something similar) within "System Settings". It won't ask the password.

Comment: You add the fact into the question that, Fedora's implementation of this is not like the one which disables password in `/etc/sudoers` as the referenced question asked. There was other mechanism working. I'll support to reopen then. Make your argument strong.

Comment: @ThePiercingPrince that behaviour is not governed by `suoders` configuration, but by PolKit configuration.

Comment: I have voted to re-open as well. There are two separate privilege escalation systems here, `sudo` and Polkit, and their configuration is independent. However, both support PAM, and the `common-auth` PAM configuration in Ubuntu has the `pam_unix` module with the `nullok_secure` option which prevents empty passwords from being used outside of TTYs mentioned in `/etc/securetty`. I'm pretty sure that's the cause here.

Comment: I've given my re-open vote too!

Comment: @muru How to get this behavior in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a note about the security systems involved: `sudo` and `gksudo` are governed by `sudoers`, but much of the GUI uses [polkit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/polkit/), whose configuration is independent of `sudoers`. There are not many common factors:

1. Ubuntu uses the `sudo` group to grant administrative privileges in both systems.
2. Both support [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM), so PAM configuration can affect both.

In particular, Fedora's default PAM configuration has:

```
$ grep 'auth.*pam_unix' /etc/pam.d -R
/etc/pam.d/password-auth-ac:auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac:auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
/etc/pam.d/system-auth:auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
/etc/pam.d/vmtoolsd:auth       sufficient       pam_unix2.so nullok
/etc/pam.d/vmtoolsd:auth       sufficient       pam_unix.so shadow nullok
/etc/pam.d/vmtoolsd:auth       required         pam_unix_auth.so shadow nullok
/etc/pam.d/password-auth:auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
```

Contrast Ubuntu:

```
$ grep 'auth.*pam_unix' /etc/pam.d -R
/etc/pam.d/common-account:account   [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_unix.so 
/etc/pam.d/common-auth:auth [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

The important point is `nullok_secure` being set for `pam_unix` in Ubuntu vs `nullok` in Fedora. According to [`man pam_unix`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pam_unix.8):

```
nullok
   The default action of this module is to not permit the user access
   to a service if their official password is blank. The nullok
   argument overrides this default and allows any user with a blank
   password to access the service.

nullok_secure
   The default action of this module is to not permit the user access
   to a service if their official password is blank. The nullok_secure
   argument overrides this default and allows any user with a blank
   password to access the service as long as the value of PAM_TTY is
   set to one of the values found in /etc/securetty.
```

Now, `/etc/securetty` does contain `:0` and other command values for graphical sessions, so `gksudo`, for example, *will* work with empty passwords.

```
# Local X displays (allows empty passwords with pam_unix's nullok_secure)
:0
:0.0
:0.1
:1
:1.0
:1.1
:2
:2.0
:2.1
:3
:3.0
:3.1
#...
```

Polkit, on the other hand, seems to leave `PAM_TTY` unset, so `securetty` doesn't affect it. `sudo`, of course, won't work, since you always run `sudo` from a terminal, and the pseudoterminal allocated to it (`/dev/ptsX`) won't be mentioned in `/etc/securetty`. You can, however, use `sudo` in the TTYs.

So how do we make Ubuntu like Fedora? Just change `nullok_secure` in `common-auth` to `nullok`:

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/pam_unix/s/nullok_secure/nullok' /etc/pam.d/common-auth
```