# How to reset password from command line

Tags: boot

I cannot reset the password. A box comes showing various commands like

```
 -a, --all -r,--repository REPOSITORY -d --delete
```

and a line at the top of the box is also present

```
     usage:passwd [options] login
```

and I dont know how to write the command.

Comment: If [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) is not what you are looking for, please **[edit]** this to clarify, which will get it reviewed for possible reopening. In particular, if you're actually looking for how to *change* your password that you know and is working, then you will not need to boot into recovery mode or do any such thing.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of the [`passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/passwd.1.html) command with the option `-d` for deleting a password is

```
sudo passwd -d LOGIN
```

Replace `LOGIN` with the username you need to reset.

Comment: I'm not sure [that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password) is really what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @EliahKagan true, it is a bit obscure why they need to reset a password but what we have so far is that they posted the manpage excerpt that is shown when we give in the `passwd` command with a wrong syntax, and it is version independent.