# Unsetting password still requires password

Tags: 16.04, sudo, password

I've followed the instructions at https://askubuntu.com/a/281093/546023 to unset my user's password and it all worked just fine.

In addition I have added the following line in sudoers

```
myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

However whenever I do `service someservice restart` it asks me for a password. What's worse no password works. In order to get it to work I need to always do `sudo service someservice restart`. Note that `sudo` never requires a password now.

Am I doing something wrong?

This is how my user settings look like right now:

[image]

Comment: The only thing you made wrong is that ***you didn't follow the warning in the referred-to post***. It explicitely says that you just deleted your own password with this method and thus can no longer supply one when Ubuntu asks for one. Luckily you added the `sudoers` line for passwordless operation, so you can revert the mess.

Comment: @PerlDuck is there no way to just remove the password completely from everything?