# Revert "sudo passwd -d `whoami`"

Tags: password, passwd

I have followed the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281074/can-i-set-my-user-account-to-have-no-password) to remove the password from an Ubuntu account. Now I want to change it all back.

I have already removed the line

```
david ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

But don't know how to revert this command:

```
sudo passwd -d `whoami`
```

Can anyone tell me how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by revert? Where is that command? I guess it should be enough to remove it for where it is (and available for execution), for example from some shellscript or .desktop file?

Comment: @sudodus How can I add back the password for the user? I guess that `-d` in the command means delete, so there must be a command with `-a`?

Comment: Did you try the command `passwd`?

Comment: @sudodus No, I have not tried that command, but I will right now. What do you mean by "shell script" ? I just ran the command in the terminal.

Comment: You may need the advice in the answer with a lot of upvotes to the following question, https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: @sudodus Thanks, I will take a look.

Comment: I was trying to understand how to get rid of that command (and did not understand how you were using it). Anyway, I think that link will help you solve the problem ...

Comment: @sudodus `passwd` worked. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :-)